# OSX proxy settings are completely ignored

Tags: python, macos, proxy

I am trying to set up my own proxy server in python ([the code](https://github.com/anapeksha/python-proxy-server/blob/master/server.py), running on port 9090) but when I change the configuration on my mac it seems like those configuration are completely ignored

The configurations:
[image: Proxy configurations]

(I of curse hit save and apply)

I also checked and my VPN is not connected...

The really odd thing is that I can even change the Web Proxy Server ip to be invalid things and still hit save and apply:
[image]
And of curse these configurations are also ignored

No help from [apple forums either](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250034851)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in some OSX versions. Apple fixed this bug in Mojave v10.14.6 so updating to this version fixes the problem.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue in 12.4